# Auto wiring an object in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using a `SpringBoot` application. I am trying to inject a service object in the controller class.I didn't use `@Autowired` above the object and constructor but still the object got injected.

```
public class Test {

    private Test1 test1;

    public Test(Test1 test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }
}
```

In the above example, `test1` got injected even though I didn't use `@autowire`d anywhere.

Could someone explain it?

Comment: From Mehraj's answer, it should also be noted that it has nothing to do with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with `Spring 4.3`,If you have a single `constructor` with dependencies as constructor parameter in your class then spring will automatically inject it for you.

As per [Spring @Autowired docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation)

> As of Spring Framework 4.3, an @Autowired annotation on such a
>   constructor is no longer necessary if the target bean only defines one
>   constructor to begin with. However, if several constructors are
>   available, at least one must be annotated to teach the container which
>   one to use.

```
public class Test {

    private Test1 test1;

    public Test(Test1 test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }
}
```